# Question about non trivial zeros of Riemann zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis

Riemann zeta function is $$\zeta(s)=\sum\frac{1}{n^s}$$ I read at wiki that the first nontrivial zero is located at $14.134725\ldots$ As far as I understand it means $$\zeta(s)=\sum\frac{1}{n^{0.5+i14.134725\ldots}}$$ Does it means $$\sum\frac{1}{n^{0.5+i14.134725\ldots}}$$ converges to $0$ for $n=1$ to infinity?

Comment: The series is divergent. The series $\sum_{n\geq1}n^{-s}$ converges for $\Re(s)>1$. The sum of the series yields a holomorphic function, that possesses an analytic continuation on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$. The Riemann Zeta function is this analytic continuation. Here, $1/2+i14.13\ldots$ is not in the domain of convergence of the series.

Comment: @polish : [look at the Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) $\eta(s) = (1-2^{1-s}) \zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} (-1)^{n+1}$ which unlike the series for $\zeta(s)$ converges for $Re(s) >0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is is not true. The sum $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}\tag1$$ converges only for $\Re(x)>1$. Nevertheless we can *extend* it on the whole complex plane (except $x=1$) so that it is holomorphic. Then, it means that the *expansion* of this function has a zero at $0.5+i14.134725...$

The false belief is that the $\zeta$ function is *defined* as $(1)$. It is defined as an expansion of this sum, not the sum itself.

Comment: What about comments saying that it converges to zero?. I really get confused on this one.

Comment: @polishvsnavajogram it doesn't converge to $0$, the series itself diverges. See my edit.

Comment: Okay so you mean if s= 0.5+i14,134725...., then it has zero somewhere within its expansion ?

Comment: @polishvsnavajogram exactly, the sum $(1)$ doesn't have any zeros (it's not equal to $0$ for any $s$), all zeros lay "behind" the line $\Re(s)=1$.